# generalized linear model with constraint from known observation?

Tags: r, anova

Suppose one has a generalized linear model with binomial error and link $g$ of the form

$$
g(\pi_j) = β_0 + β_1 x_j  \qquad  j = 1,2,···
$$

where $x$ is the explanatory variable. Suppose that we also know that

$$
g(\pi_0) = β_0 + β_1 x_0
$$

for a single pair of known values $\{\pi_0, x_0\}$.

Would anyone know how I can fit this model?

Comment: I think this question is pretty clear (at least if I'm interpreting it correctly), and interesting.  I edited & voted to reopen.  If the revised version of the question does *not* express what you meant, please revise it to say what you do mean.

Comment: how would I go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve the constraint equation and use an *offset* to fit the resulting model.  That is,

$$
\begin{split}
g(\pi_0) & = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x_0 \\
\beta_0 & = g(\pi_0) - \beta_1 x_0
\end{split}
$$

Substituting into your regression equation:

$$
\begin{split}
g(\pi_j) & = g(\pi_0) - \beta_1 x_0 + \beta_1 x_j \\
         & = g(\pi_0) + \beta_1 (x_j - x_0)
\end{split}
$$

So you need to fix the intercept at $g(\pi_0)$ and use $x-x_0$ as your predictor variable.

In R, you would do this as:

```
glm(p ~ -1 + I(x-x0) + offset(plogis(p0)),
     family=binomial, data = ...)
```

The `-1` suppresses estimation of the intercept, `plogis()` is the logit function [the default link, or $g()$, for the binomial]. I used `p` instead of `pi` for the response because `pi` is a built-in variable in R: might still work, but v. confusing ...